# Flutter Returning (gradle-related) Error on running on Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I **downloaded this flutter app** template from here - https://flutterawesome.com/ui-implementation-of-coffee-shop-app-for-flutter/

But when I tried to run the app on Android, but it is **returning this Error**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
'UI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             314ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

**I'm developing this app, for both iOS and Android. How do I fix this issue?**

Comment: I can't see the attached template.